# DrRacket Custom Keybindings

Tags: scheme, racket, key-bindings

In [DrRacket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/index.html) IDE,
I would like to change the default `C-F6` shortcut for shift-focus with `C-Tab`.

In meta code it should be:

```lisp
    #lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang

    (keybinding "c:tab" (λ (editor evt) (send editor shift-focus)))
```

Unfortunately `shift-focus` is not part of the 
DrRacket API. I found a [reference](https://github.com/racket/gui/blob/master/gui-lib/framework/private/keymap-global.rkt) to it, but I am unable to covert it in a procedure to use for `keybinding`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html#%28part._defining-shortcuts%29, you can bind the key to an existing command as follows:

```
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang

(define (rebind key command)
  (keybinding
   key
   (λ (ed evt)
     (send (send ed get-keymap) call-function
           command ed evt #t))))

(rebind "c:tab" "shift-focus")
```

Comment: I had to restart DrRacket in order to make this solution work, because there were some leftovers from a previous (failed) attempt to change the keybinding. This was triggering an error as soon as I would press c:tab. After restart of DrRacket and freshly adding the above solution through Edit->Add User-defined Keybindings, everything works fine.